# PyQt QFileSystemModel missing argument in MyWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a program in PyQt5 and want to have a tree view with files at the side of it.  I found some code online that works but when I want to implement it in my (beginning) of the program i get errors, I have got rid of a lot but now I keep have this:

```
window = MyWindow()     
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'QFileSystemModel'
```

Because I am starting with Qt I don't know a lot so it must be something stupid.  Eventually I want a variable pad from the current folder to import and record data to, and I want to be able to create new folders an select multiple files.

PS: my English isn't great.

```
import os, sys
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

qtcreator_file  = "mainwindow.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtcreator_file)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, QFileSystemModel):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, QFileSystemModel)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self, QFileSystemModel)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.FileStuckture.setSortingEnabled( True )
        self.FileStuckture.setObjectName("treeView")

        self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.dirModel.setRootPath( 'D:\DemoGIPhoofdmap' )

        def selectZeroZero( path ) :
            if dirModel.rowCount( dirModel.index( path ) ) :
                FileStuckture.setCurrentIndex( dirModel.index( 0, 0, dirModel.index( path ) ) )

        self.dirModel.directoryLoaded.connect( selectZeroZero )

        self.FileStuckture.setModel( dirModel )
        self.FileStuckture.setRootIndex( dirModel.index( 'D:\DemoGIPhoofdmap' ) )

        self.FileStuckture.setHeaderHidden( True )
        self.FileStuckture.hideColumn( 1 )
        self.FileStuckture.hideColumn( 2 )
        self.FileStuckture.hideColumn( 3 )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What kind of errors? You have to be bit more specific.

Comment: When I run the code this is the only error that I ge now.
window = MyWindow()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'QFileSystemModel'

Comment: I am not sure about the whole __init__ function of your MyWindow.
But clearly the error is because the __init__ function expects a parameter and your are not passing any parameters.
window = MyWindow() needs to be replaced by window = MyWindow(<here you must pass an instance of QFileSystemModel >)

Comment: Thanks for the resposne
I agree, but I am just starting with this so I don't know what to pass how...?

Comment: @Robbe It makes no sense to pass in a `QFileSystemModel`. Remove the three lines after `class MyWindow`, and add this line `def __init__(self):` and this line `super().__init__(self)` (indented).

Comment: Now I have this:
`class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.FileStuckture.setSortingEnabled( True )
        self.FileStuckture.setObjectName("treeView")

        self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()`

And get this error:
`super().__init__(self)
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MyWindow was never called`

Comment: @Robbe Sorry: that should have been `super().__init__()` (i.e. with no `self` argument). And that line needs to be indented to the same level as the lines below it.

Comment: no proplem, thanks!
Now on line 17:
`self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()`
I get this error:
`self.dirModel = QFileSystemModel()
NameError: name 'QFileSystemModel' is not defined`

Comment: @Robbe Use `QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel`. But there are other errors in the code. For example, it needs to use `self.dirModel` and `self.FileStuckture` **everywhere**, and the file-path should be written like this: `r'D:\DemoGIPhoofdmap'`.